# Comparing & Copying Newer Files

Tags: powershell

I have a series of E-mail templates stored on a DFS fileshare.

I would like to have a logon script so that when a user logs on, it will cycle through each template in `\\LAN\Files\Office Templates\Outlook`, compare the `LastWriteTime` and then copy across any of the newer files from the DFS share to the local folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates`

Currently the folders look like this:
[image: folders]

(I am aware at the minute they have the same date, but they won't in the future)

If anyone can help me with this then I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code with which you have problems. SO is not a code writing service. Also take a look at following links: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [XCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy), it's built into most versions of windows and is purpose designed for copy operations.

```
xcopy <Source> <Destination> <Parameters>
```

It's got many options, so worth reading the documentation link above.

Your copy is the most simple and needs no extra params. By default this will copy any files from `Source` that are newer, or do not exist, to `Destination`:

```
xcopy "\\LAN\Files\Office Templates\Outlook" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates"
```

---

Or the other option is to use [Group Policy Preferences](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/5415/Using-Group-Policy-Preferences-for-copying-files.html), but that's offtopic for here, more suited to ServerFault.

Comment: Thank you, James. As you have suggested, XCOPY definitely looks like the way to do this and is much simpler than my method. I had thought about GPO as an alternative but your suggestions is by far better.